# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android

I am dealing with that problem:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
No virtual method getActiveNetwork()Landroid/net/Network; in class Landroid/net/ConnectivityManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.net.ConnectivityManager' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
```

There is my code:

```
 public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (connectivityManager != null) {


            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
                if (capabilities != null) {
                    if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {

                        return true;
                    } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {

                        return true;
                    } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)) {

                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    return false;}
```

there is the stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getActiveNetwork()Landroid/net/Network; in class Landroid/net/ConnectivityManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.net.ConnectivityManager' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
   at com.olgazelenko.esofer.MainMenu.isNetworkAvailable(MainMenu.java:307)
   at com.olgazelenko.esofer.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:75)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

does someone know how that can be fixed?

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace.

Comment: check it out: https://justpaste.it/5q7ja

Comment: Please include it in your question and not on any website.

Comment: Also this is not the complete stack trace.

Comment: ok check it out now

Comment: looks like a method that was added in a recent version, check if you're using at least api level 23 of android sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Error occurs often when you have compiled with one version of your dependency but are running the code with a different version.

Here, it looks that `com.olgazelenko.esofer.MainMenu.isNetworkAvailable(MainMenu.java:307)`  calls a method from android which is not found during your execution.

This method, getActiveNetwork, seemed to be added in Android SDK API Level 23. You maybe try to use it in a older version. see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getActiveNetwork(). Try to upgrade your minSdkVersion : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element

Comment: so basically i have to upgrade my minSkVersion to 23? i am on 22 right now.

Comment: Exactly https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element

Comment: ok got it.. i hope it is gonna work after i'm doing an update on my published app... thanks mate, answer accepted!